# How can I apply the McCormick Envelopes to the product of two binary variables?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization, binary-programming

I've seen the McCormick envelopes applied many times to the product of two continuous variables, but I can't seem to find when both of them are binaries. Also, I applied the restrictions as described bellow, and they don't work because they don't make sense when both of them are 1.

the restrictions:
$$
\begin{align*}
w_{i j} &\geq x_{i}^{L} \cdot x_{j} + x_{i} \cdot x_{j}^{L} - x_{i}^{L} \cdot x_{j}^{L}\\
w_{i j} &\geq x_{i}^{U} \cdot x_{j} + x_{i} \cdot x_{j}^{U} - x_{i}^{U} \cdot x_{j}^{U}\\
w_{i j} &\leq x_{i}^{U} \cdot x_{j} + x_{i} \cdot x_{j}^{L} - x_{i}^{U} \cdot x_{j}^{L}\\
w_{i j} &\leq x_{i} \cdot x_{j}^{U} + x_{i}^{L} \cdot x_{j} - x_{i}^{L} \cdot x_{j}^{U}\\
x^{L} &\leq x \leq x^{U} \qquad~ w^{L} \leq w \leq w^{U}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem and please write something like formulas with "MathJax" in the question and not via link which shows a picture with the formulas.

Comment: Mc Cormick envelopes ? What is it ? Could you give a reference ?

Comment: @Kevin Dietrich Congratulations for having patiently written the formulas !

Comment: Sorry, this was the first time I posted here. I'll be more carefull in the future. I applied the formulas written now (thank you @KevinDietrich) but I got terrible results because I created w as continuous, but changed xi and xj to continuous as well. This created a problem as both xi and xj were comming as random values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $0$ for $x^L$ and $1$ for $x^U$ yields:
\begin{align}
w_{i j} &\ge 0 \\
w_{i j} &\ge x_j + x_i - 1 \\
w_{i j} &\le x_j \\
w_{i j} &\le x_i
\end{align}
This is the usual linearization of $w_{ij} = x_i x_j$. See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt. I got confused because I assumed that I had to change xi and xj to continuous too and this was giving me weird results.